# Error in as.data.frame.default(data, optional = TRUE) when knitting a r markdown file

Tags: r, r-markdown, logistic-regression

When I try to knit my RMD I get the following - Line 20 Error in as.data.frame.default(data, optional = TRUE): cannot coerce class '"function"' to a data frame. I can run the code in my script with no issues and in fact the first time I tried it worked but then I had to change few options (echo, eval and error) and then I started getting the error. Here is the line in question
`

```
model <- glm(GGPA_3.4 ~ Age + Gender + UGPA, df, family = "binomial")
summary(model)
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
model <- glm(GGPA_3.4 ~ Age + Gender + UGPA,  family = "binomial", data = df)
summary(model)
```

Wondering if the order of the arguments out of order caused the function to error. The doc `glm()` says for the `family` argument *For glm this can be a character string naming a family function, a family function or the result of a call to a family function* Maybe try `family=binomial` also to fix the error

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. In the first chunk I had the option "eval = FALSE" and that's when I started having issues. Once I removed it everything was back to normal.